# Should I use a different partition for "/Users" in Windows 7 (64bit)?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I am not very experienced with setting up new computers but I just bought a new computer and started installing all my software, I received a message that my hard-drive was full, impossible I thought it is a 500GB Hard Drive and I have not installed anywhere near that much.  That is when I realized that the hard drive has a partition and everything is on the C:drive (58.5 GB) and the E:Drive (397 GB) is empty.  First of why doesn't this add up to 500 GB.  Second and the reason I am writing this, is what problems will I have if I simply move my Users directory to the E drive and remove it from C:?  Would it make sense to reformat and start over?   Should I eliminate the partition and go with one big hard drive?  How would I set it up with a partition so that all the Data is on one drive and the Sys Files and Programs are on the other?   Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

a) 500gb is what the vendor of the harddisk tells you. he is not lying but he tells you 500gb in terms of "base 10", while your computer counts the bits and bytes with "base 2", your computer sees roughly 465gb.

b) its just up to you. 50g is fine for the base system if you store everything else somewhere .. else :) moving the users directory to E: is fine as well, gives every user of your system its own folder on the big partition.

Answer (score 1):

A [gigabyte (GB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte) is actually 10,000,000,000 bytes, being a decimal [SI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) unit.

What is commonly called a gigabyte of RAM, is actually a [gibibyte (GiB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte), being a binary unit defined by the [IEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60027).

Keeping your files on a separate hard drive or partition makes a lot of sense, as it makes backing up files easier, as well as reinstalling your operating system.

In Windows 7 you can just drag the folders to the other partition, and Windows will automatically know where they are.  You can place hidden symbolic links in their place (using the MKLINK command), pointing to the new locations, to make everything failsafe (that's what I do).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't move C:\Users, as this can get you into trouble if not done correctly.

Another option is to delete the empty partition and add its space to C:.
This will give you 58.5+397 GB on the system drive and simplify your life.

Add a comment to this answer if you would like to know more.